# windows 7 with ubuntu on virtual box on asus x401a very slow

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, cpu

I installed virtual box and loaded ubuntu 12.04.  Everything seemed to work once loaded, but it simply was dead slow.

I saw afterwards that the processor on this laptop, intel B970, does not support virtualization in the bios.

Does this prevent the possibility of getting this to work properly?  Or does anyone know a fix to this?

Comment: What are the system specs? How much RAM did you allocate to the VM?

Comment: Here are the specs:
http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Asus---14%26%2334%3B-Laptop---4GB-Memory---320GB-Hard-Drive---Matte-Deep-Blue-Square/5732421.p?id=1218688220686&skuId=5732421#tab=specifications

I allocated 1 Gigabyte of RAM to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using virtual box, I am now using vmware and the difference is night and day.  Definitely is useable now, in case anyone is having a similar problem.